# An interesting version of the problem "balls into bins"

Tags: probability, combinatorics, computer-science

Consider *n* people, each has *k* identical balls. Each people choose *k* different bins from *m* bins, constrained by the condition that there are no two people choose exactly the same k bins. For instance, there are 6 people A,B,C,D,E,F, each hold 2 balls and there are 4 different bins①，②，③，④.  If A choose ①②, B choose ①③， C choose ①④, D choose ②③，E choose ②④，and F choose③④, then we call it a proper configuration since no two people choose exactly the same 2 bins

Now each people flip a unbiased coin, if HEAD appears then he put all his ball into the k bins he has choosen, each bin with one ball. He will do nothing if TAIL appears. Here comes the problem, given a proper configration, everyone flip a coin and behave the way we described above.  Can we infer the coin result of each people based on the number of balls in each bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general.  For example, suppose there are four people $A,B,C,D$ and four bins 1,2,3,4, and suppose that $A$ chooses 1 and 2, $B$ chooses 3 and 4, $C$ chooses 1 and 4, and $D$ chooses 2 and 3. In this case, there's no way to distinguish between $A$ and $B$ flipping heads and $C$ and $D$ flipping tails, versus $A$ and $B$ flipping tails and $C$ and $D$ flipping heads.

If you want the choices of bins to be sufficient to determine the choice of people, then you need the bin choices to be linearly independent as vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_2^m$.  That is, the choices should be the basis codewords for a [binary linear code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code) of type $[m,k,2]$.

**Edit:** As Hagen von Eitzen points out, using a binary linear code is sufficient to determine the coin flips, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Having a code is *sufficient*, but I guess not necessarily *necessary*. We get mote info then whether a bin contains an even or odd number of balls - we get the exact number, so might be able to see more than what the code (reduction mod 2) sees. For example, with three people, two balls and three bins, $A=(1,2), B=(1,3), C=(2,3)$ the problem is solvable in spite of $\mathbb Z_2$ linear dependence.

Comment: That's true--cycles of odd length are allowed.  I suppose the obvious conjecture is that it is necessary and sufficient for the associated graph to have no cycles of even length.

Comment: Hi,Jim Belk,thank you for your consideration. What do you mean by 'the bin choices to be linearly independent'?  I'm not so familiar with coding theory, can you give any instance to show what choices are independent and what choices are not?

Comment: @Charles Linearly independent as vectors whose entries are $1$'s and $0$'s.  Note that the final number of balls in each urn can be thought of as a vector which is the sum of some subset of the placement vectors chosen by the individual people.

Comment: @JimBelk I guess the placement vectors of the four people in the example you give above are dependent, because the sum of the placement vector of A and C, which is (1100) and (0011) respectively, equals the sum of those of B and D. Is this case common in general? Put it in another way, given the m,n and k,can we bound the probability that there's no way to infer the coin results of each people?